# Travel times during peak hours in Los Angeles

Tags: usa, automobiles, california, traffic, southern-california

Traffic patterns repeat themselves.  I've tried getting driving directions with Google Maps, but it seems like they only provide the estimate with either no traffic being on the way, or with only the current traffic situation being accounted for.

What if I need to arrive at time X to place Y from place Z?  What time do I depart, taking the prior traffic patterns in consideration (which I'm unfamiliar with, since it's my first time being in the area)?

In other words, where do I get the information about the average traffic congestion between two given points at a given time window on a given day of the week?  (I'm currently in need of such information for travelling from Riverside to LA, but it would also be useful for directions between San Jose and San Francisco etc.)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about standard traffic patterns.

Comment: Taking the standard work day being 9-5 the rush hour traffic starts about 2 hours before start of work day and lasts for about 3 hours.  And in reverse 1 hour before to 2 hours after the end of the work day.

Comment: @Karlson I think it could probably be edited to fit within our rules - just needs to stress that it's for when you're planning travel to a city you don't know, and are trying to find out ways to estimate the likely travel in advance

Comment: @Gagravarr That's why there are apps like Waze and now Google Maps that allow you to see traffic real time.  Including detour options

Comment: If you can give instructions on using one of those for "what time do I need to plan to leave tomorrow, to go from (eg) a hotel I've never been to, to (eg) an office I've never been to the other side of town, roughly" then I think we have an answer!

Comment: @Karlson, that is not true; depending on the area, traffic patterns are very different; in the SF Bay Area, almost all highways are jammed up between 15:00 and 19:00, whereas other areas are more like 16:00 to 18:00.  I'm currently in LA, I have never been here, and I have no idea what their traffic situation is like.  Waiting until real time to see the traffic congestion to get to a given place on time is kinda like asking for trouble — it may been too late...

Comment: @cnst Given that traffic may also be dependent on accidents, construction, and other factors like rain or the sun that's all the options you have.  The only traffic you can comfortably predict is rush hour traffic.

Comment: @Karlson, rain and sun affecting traffic in a major metro area?  i don't think so.

Comment: @cnst I guess you have not tried driving during sunrise or the sunset into the sun.  It creates traffic since people naturally slow down.  Same in the rain because of the potential for aquaplaning including Los Angeles.  Same issue occurs on upgrades because people don't press harder on the gas to give their car more power to climb and so on.

Comment: Yep, whenever it rains here in sunny soCal, it's like most drivers have forgotten that it ever rained before! Check out [SigAlert](http://www.sigalert.com) and I recently read a column that was very flattering about Waze.

Comment: @Karlson I don't get it. How are standard traffic patterns *not* related to traveling (by car, bus or taxi)?

Comment: @Gilles Traveling by car is affected by traffic on a one off basis.  Long term/Average traffic pattern study won't help you on a given day because on that day some idiot decides to jump in front of a moving car on a highway and your traffic patterns are now useless.

Comment: @Karlson, are you trying to claim that real time traffic is immune to someone jumping on a highway, but traffic patterns aren't?

Comment: @cnst I am claiming that traffic patterns are only relevant during rush hour.  Beyond that they are not necessarily governed by the rules of averages and it matters more to know what is happenning on the road now then what had happenned there in the past year.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use Google Maps traffic information to estimate driving time for a specific date/time?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/27485/can-i-use-google-maps-traffic-information-to-estimate-driving-time-for-a-specifi)

Comment: I suggest you visit Google Maps on a similar day (i.e., weekday, but Fridays might have more p.m. traffic) at the time you will be going. Obviously something weird _may_ happen, but no source will help with that. Driving time in the San Francisco Bay Area during rush hour is, I'd estimate, usually double, sometimes treble, what it is midday.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the usual maps.google, an alternative is http://livetraffic.tomtom.com.

On the left, you can enter the time you are leaving and it figures out when you'll arrive, or enter the time you want to arrive and it figures out when you should leave.

It is based on many different data points, so it is pretty accurate.

It's a good alternative to maps.google, for the specific case of estimating times (including traffic variations during the day/week).