# How is the range of Google Maps new drive time feature defined?

Tags: online-resources, driving, routes, maps

I just noticed Google Maps new feature.  It allows the user to get approximate drive times for a specific date and time using average traffic conditions.  This is a feature which [many people have been wanting for quite some time](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/27485/can-i-use-google-maps-traffic-information-to-estimate-driving-time-for-a-specifi).  It allows the user to choose to depart at a specific time or arrive at a specific time.  In the later case it recommends a time for the user to leave.  The drive time is given as a possible range of times (see the screencap below).

My question is; how is this range of times defined?  Is it the minimum to maximum range, the 90% confidence interval, or perhaps the 25th to 75th percentile?

[image]

Comment: From experimenting, it looks like the bottom end of the range never changes, no matter what date and start time you put in. Therefore this seems to be the time with no traffic, and if you put in a date and time when it's rush hour, then there may be zero probability of getting there that fast. As an example, I put in this route https://goo.gl/maps/GzABo , and IMO there is zero probability of completing it in 35 min during rush hour.

Comment: IMO this question should be closed or even deleted since only a Google employee can answer it (and even if one reads it they very likely won't).

Comment: @chx That is an assumption on your part.  I am asking for a definition of the units, not information about Google's proprietary algorithm for calculating the numbers.  Useful information has units associated with it, and I find it unlikely for Google to not have published the definition they chose to use somewhere (blog, help files, etc.).

Comment: @MarkMayo Really?  Perhaps it is the scientist in me, but the two questions are completely unrelated IMO.  I am asking about their definition of the range they publish, not about how close that range is to what one might actually experience.

Comment: I think as regards the actual practical upshot, Mark's suggestion is appropriate.

Comment: Since this question is headed towards being closed as a duplicate of a completely unrelated question, I've [tried asking the Google Maps team directly](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/maps/iVaKdxUhuMw/gxb004cEp7wJ).

Comment: I apologise if I'm wrong, but I'd expect a definition of how the range is calculated would give you the accuracy.  If we're wanting the actual algorithm, well that's probably more of a software question than a travel one :/

Comment: @chx There is in fact a Google employee working on “geospatial solutions“ no less among the top users on this site.

Comment: @jpatokal (cough) might be in your wheelhouse?

Comment: @MarkMayo Sorry, not familiar with the guts of this particular feature; I couldn't tell you the details if I was; and even if I did, the formula would be liable to change without notice.  So this question is likely to remain unanswered unless Google chooses to write this up in a public blog post or something.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a software question.

Comment: Would this be an appropriate question for the site if it were reworded like this: If I take Google's advice on when to leave, how likely am I to get to my destination on time?

Comment: @wrschneider I think that is an excellent re-wording of the question.  You should ask it!