# Google Maps recommended "leave at" time: how reliable is this?

Tags: driving, maps, traffic

Google Maps provides a feature to estimate your arrival time based on typical traffic along your route.  It provides this time as a range, e.g., "typically 1h - 1h 50m"  Based on that, if you select to arrive at a specific time (vs. leave now or depart at), it will tell you what time to leave given the high end of the range.

My question is: if you follow the advice and leave yourself the high end of the estimated travel time range (1h 50m in my example above), how likely are you to arrive at your destination on time?

This is a rewording of this closed question:
[How is the range of Google Maps new drive time feature defined?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44578/how-is-the-range-of-google-maps-new-drive-time-feature-defined)

Comment: I fear it is not the same all over the world. It also will depend a lot on things like weather and local reactions to it.

Comment: How is this question different than the original (you yourself said it's only a rewording)? If it isn't and it's the same as the one closed as off-topic, I think this one should be closed too.

Comment: This seems extremely dependent on location and circumstance.  Could you perhaps be more specific?

Comment: For some reason, Google Maps is only showing me single times, not ranges. I could offer an answer regarding the accuracy of the individual times I see, but I don't know where those times fall within the ranges.

Comment: Difference in question: the original question was asking about their approach for determining the interval; I'm asking about how I should use the information as a driver.

Comment: I am asking in context of US.  What my question gets down to is, how much variability is already accounted for in the range Google provides, and how much additional margin of safety do you need to add to that range?

Comment: The question says "based on typical traffic" and not on "actual traffic". So you need more information about real time conditions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off topic and a better fit at [Google Maps & Earth Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/maps)

Comment: Google can sometimes be hopelessly inaccurate. While road works near where I live were in progress (for 6 months, so they should have been able to collect some real data) it was sending people on 10-mile detour with speed limits of 30 or 40 MPH all the way, to avoid a tailback on a 70 MPH road which  rarely caused more than 5 minutes delay - i.e. adding maybe 20 minutes to the journey time and with a complicated route with plenty of opportunities for strangers to get lost and waste even more time.

Answer (score 4):

Google is surprising close to the estimate. I'm baffled each time I use it!

That being said, google has a pretty hard time estimating red zones. I've had google tell me a traffic spot will take 20 minutes, when it actually took me two hours! This is not normal of course (this was a highway in Brazil), but I still always just look at googles estimate as a whole (E.G. 1hr 50mn), look at the route it wants to take me through, and make my own judgments. I'd probably end up leaving 20 minutes before a google estimate of two hours.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on where you are, Google is surprisingly accurate, or surprisingly inaccurate.

I find Google more accurate in countries that are more 'developed'. Very decent estimates in, say, Germany. Not so much in, say, Kenya.