# Fastest/cheapest New York airport to get to Brooklyn

Tags: airport-transfer, new-york-city, jfk, ewr, lga

Which of the three main New York airports (EWR, LGA, JFK) should I fly to to be the fastest/cheapest way possible to Brooklyn (Moore St, Brooklyn, NY 11206)?

I'm planning to arrive in NY at about 9/10 pm on a saturday. We are two people traveling with carry-on only, so heavy luggage is not an issue.

Comment: This should help you out: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/99733/google-maps-recommended-leave-at-time-how-reliable-is-this

Comment: Probably La Guardia, but maybe JFK.  It depends on your personal balance between fast (taxi) and cheap (walk) and options in between (public transportation).

Comment: I forgot to mention in my question that i'm arriving on a saturday(edited it already). I dont know if that may affect the taxi option (traffic). I don't mind walking at all but don't really want to be lost in the middle of the night (never been to New York before). But i wouldn't mind a option including public transportation and walking.

Comment: It may also be that your choice of airport is constrained by airline and departure city.

Comment: I'm Portuguese but i'm flying from Toronto, so i have many options. That's the main reason why i'm trying to find out what would be my best arrival airport.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JFK gives you straightforward public transit options.  You can take the AirTrain people-mover to the Sutphin Blvd subway station, and then it's a straight shot on the J/Z line to Flushing Av (J) or Myrtle Av (Z) which are within a few blocks of your destination.  Total cost $7.75 per person.

From LGA, you could take one of several [buses](https://www.laguardiaairport.com/to-from-airport/public-transportation) and connect to the M train, which eventually stops at Flushing Av.  That costs $2.75.  Some people might find buses harder to navigate than AirTrain, and they're subject to road traffic.

From EWR, you have a monorail, then a train ride, followed by a subway journey with at least one transfer, and it will be closer to $15 per person.

Comment: There is also no subway service to JFK.  From JFK, you can get to the subway by bus or airtrain.  From La Guardia, you can take a bus.  In both cases, the subway system is at least once removed from the airport.  LGA requires a transfer in the subway system, but the total time is similar.

Comment: Thank you for you answer! Just one more thing, regarding the comment about buses being subject to traffic, do you think there will be a great amount of traffic on a saturday around 10pm?

Comment: @mratinho: I don't have any knowledge about that.  About a year ago, there were reports that due to construction, there were severe delays getting in and out of LGA by car, which I presume would also apply to bus.  I don't know whether that's still the case.